# Is present National Instruments Measurement Studio compatible with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, measurement-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Pro.
I am using VB.NET to create a GUI windows app to manage an NI USB-6343 DAQ.

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible with"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NI Measurement Studio 2015 does sadly not support VS2015 (and so also not VS2017), it supports VS 2013, 2012 and 2010. There is a workaround for 2015 see this [link](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/F01DDED92E62447286257F5E0071048D), that might also work for VS2017.

Update:

> **Measurement Studio 2019 Beta**
>
> Measurement Studio extends the power of Microsoft Visual Studio with a
> set of .NET tools designed for building engineering test and
> measurement applications.  Try out the beta to use:
>
> - Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 integration
> - Debug Visualizer

see http://www.ni.com/de-ch/support/software-technology-preview.html

**Update 2**

NI Measurement Studio 2019 supports VS2015, VS2017 and VS2019, see

https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/software-products/download.measurement-studio.html

and
[image]
https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019RD9SAM&l=de-CH

Comment: See as well https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AEKozminski.MeasurementStudio-ProfessionalNETToolsforEngineeri#qna